# Как в конфигурационном файле Web Pack изменить путь до выходного файла

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack4

У меня есть web pack конфиг такого типа:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  // mode: 'development',
  cache: true,
  entry: './src/main.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    library: 'asset',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

...

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  // filename: config.build.index,
  title: process.env.npm_package_description,
  template: 'index.html',
  inject: true,
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: true
  },
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
  serviceWorkerLoader: ''
})
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
    to: 'static',
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
]),
....
```

При формировании файлов получается следующий вид проекта.

```
/static (статические файлы)
index.html (подключает <script src ='main.bundle.js'>...)
main.bundle.js
vendors.bundle.js
sw.js
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне изменить конфиг WebPack что бы файлы сборки изменились на такую структуру ?

```
/static (статические файлы)
/static/main.bundle.js
/static/vendors.bundle.js
/static/sw.js 
index.html (подключает <script src ='/static/main.bundle.js'>...)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
      entry: './src/main.js',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue']
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library: 'Vue',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/static/')
      },

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // filename: config.build.index,
      title: process.env.npm_package_description,
      template: 'index.html',
      filename: '../index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
      },
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
      serviceWorkerLoader: ''
    })

   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        to: '',
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),
```